# References by category (Journals, proceedings)

Tags: natbib, article

How can I print references by category in `\documentclass{article}` using `natbib`?
for example articles, proceedings,...?
Thanks

I am new to LATEX and searched a lot. I appreciate if you can help me.
I would like to print my papers in my CV sorted by category. how can I change the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}%itemizeing
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}

\begin{document}
%------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\nobibliography{bibsample}

%------------------------------
\section*{PUBLICATIONS}
\begin{itemize}
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \item[]
  \bibentry{no1}.
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \item[]
  \bibentry{no2}.
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \item[]
  \bibentry{no3}.
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \item[]
  \bibentry{no4}.
  %-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

and here is my sample bibfile

```
@inproceedings{no1,
address = {city1},
author = {familyname, name},
booktitle = {book1},
title = {{title1}},
year = {2012}
}

@inproceedings{no2,
address = {city1},
author = {familyname, name},
booktitle = {book2},
doi = {10........},
month = jun,
number = {10},
pages = {1000--1100},
publisher = {American Society of ....},
title = {{title2}},
year = {2013}
}


@article{no3,
author = {familyname, name},
journal = {submitted for publication},
doi = {10.0000},
journal = {Journal2},
month = feb,
number = {1},
pages = {200-300},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{65465653}},
volume = {1},
year = {2014}
}
@article{no4,
author = {familyname, name},
journal = {submitted for publication},
doi = {10.0000},
journal = {Journal2},
month = feb,
number = {1},
pages = {200-300},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{65465653}},
volume = {1},
year = {2014}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You may use `multibib` or `multibbl`.

Comment: Or you may consider `biblatex`/`biber` if that's an option...

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using package `biblatex` as seen so many times on TeX.SX.

[image: houmanCvPublications]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview={XYZ null null 1.00}}

\begin{document}

\nocite{angenendt,aksin,companion,aristotle:physics}
\printbibheading[title=Publications]
\printbibliography[type=article,title=Articles,heading=subbibliography]
\printbibliography[type=book,title=Books,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```